# How is IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter() in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Is there something similar to Delphi's [`IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter) function to add a `'\'` character to the end of a path string without writing the literal `"\\"` inside of my `.cpp` file, or any other place of my project?

```
#include <shlobj.h>

TCHAR szFolderPath[MAX_PATH];

if (SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, szFolderPath, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, FALSE))
{
    cout << szFolderPath << endl;

}
```

Comment: Is c++ 17 available to you?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe, i'm using **VS 2013**.

Comment: calling this code C++ is offensive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, there is the Shell API's [`PathCchAddBackslash()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707078.aspx) function (it is safer to use than [`PathAddBackslash()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773561.aspx)).

```
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <Pathcch.h>

TCHAR szFolderPath[MAX_PATH];

if (SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, szFolderPath, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, FALSE))
{
    PathCchAddBackslash(szFolderPath, MAX_PATH);
    cout << szFolderPath << endl;
}
```

Otherwise, it shouldn't be hard to implement this yourself in C++.